# WPF localization with ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, resourcedictionary

At the moment I integrate the current strings like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="lang/Dictionary.en-US.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Is there a possibility to do this dynamically in my code behind files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can just do something like:

```
var res = new ResourceDictionary {Source = new Uri("somepath")};
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(res);
```

Note: This is off the top of my head on not tested but it should work